# I want to show calendar events in numbers instead of stack JavaScript full calendar?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using Full calendar for showing events in calendar. I have different packages types and all events are showing in the form of a stack.

**My requirement is that I want to show all events of the same package type in the form of numbers.**

**For Example.**

if I selected pacakge 1 and its events are 5. and I drag these events on calendar then show one row with count 5. and when select package 2 and its events are 10 and after drag it must be shown in 2nd row with count 10. If any further query, you can ask. Thanks

Each package has different number of events that are populate on the selection
[image]

In the screen 1 and 2 show You can see the details.
[image]

Comment: if you could describe a bit more with desired output and which package you are using

Comment: I am using all packages and all packages has different number of events. I want to show only number of events in one row for a particular package. i.e if I selected pacakge 1 and its events are 5. and I drag these events on calendar then show one row with count 5. and when select package 2 and its events are 10 and after drag it must be shown in 2nd row with count 10. If any further query, you can ask. Thanks

Comment: If you only want to show one row for each package then why not just have one event per package? The detail of the exact contents could be held in a description field of the event which is shown in a popover when you click or hover on the event. I don't understand the point of having lots of separate events it you aren't actually going to show them. Maybe I've missed something from your explanation.

Comment: @ADyson First of thanks for your answer to this thread. Actually, the events are slots(it is related to time i.e if 12 events on the same day its means that each event will occur after 1 hour). Can you help me with this issue?

Comment: Ok. But if you're just going to show one row showing "10" written into it, then by definition you can't also have 10 separate rows, one for each slot. When would that ever be displayed?  You need to choose which thing you want, I think.

Comment: P.S. Are you expecting that the individual 1-hour slots would only shown when you change to the timegrid view or something like that? I'm just trying to work out the logic you're thinking of.

Comment: @ADyson I am attaching a picture it might help you. By the way, if you have any further queries you can ask me freely thanks.

Comment: Ok. No, that's not possible. I mean you _could_ add a single event to represent the "10" bit, and then have separate events for the individual slots. The problem is the "+ more" link isn't controllable. You have to fix that for all cells (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover). So you can't do it so that the individual slots will always be hidden.

Comment: @ADyson And what's your suggestion about delete multiple events from the calendar when we press the trash delete button?

Comment: I would suggest giving all the "child" events the same group ID or something, then you can find all of the related ones quite easily.

Comment: @ADyson Can you please give me an example?

Comment: Example of what exactly? It's just a property of the event object. Then you can filter the events by that ID when you come to find the associated ones to delete.

Comment: actually when i delete any event i want to delete 5 siblings events i'm not able to do that using jquery i shows an alert that "this slot does not exist" i think it clicks on itself again please help me